# Custom UIViewAnimationTransition on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm wondering if there is any chance to create a custom transition animation between Views, as a "cube":
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/wp-content/uploads/pdl-cubed.jpg

I've took a look for some example, without any success, do you know some, is even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
UIViewController* viewCtrl = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = @"cube"; //Note: undocumented API, will probably cause App Store rejection
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
transition.delegate = self;

[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewCtrl animated:YES];

[viewCtrl release];
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. You will need to have 2 views and a bit of Core Animation 3D transforms.